# Indexing a 2d array using a list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to index a 2d array based on a list of arrays.

```
a = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]])

idx = [np.array([0,1], np.array([0,2])]
```

What I want then want is that the first element in the idx should give `a[0,1]` and the second `a[0,2]` and so on such that:

```
a[fixed_idx] = array([2,3])
```

Comment: `list(np.array([0,1]),np.array([0,2])` is completely invalid syntax. What are you trying to express there?

Comment: `a[0,[1,2]]`, `a[( np.array([0,0]), np.array([1,2]) )]` are equivalent ways of selecting those 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could do:

```
a[tuple(zip(*idx))]
```

output: `array([2, 3])`

Comment: That's the problem. OP apparently wants `[1,2]` as the output.

Comment: @richardec that might be an error, `a[0,1], a[0,2]` is `(2,3)`

Comment: Yes, I understand. Possible the OP meant to use `0,0` and `0,1`...?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have more indices, like:

```
dummy_idx = [n for n in np.random.randint(100, size=(1000000, 2))]
```

Then you need to get advanced indices `x` and `y` such that `a[x, y]` gives what you expect.

There are two easy ways to do that:

1. `x, y = zip(*dummy_idx)`
2. `x, y = np.transpose(dummy_idx)`

First method quite a slow because `numpy` arrays are not designed for fast iteration and hence it takes quite a long time to access their items in comparison with `numpy` vectorised actions. On the other hand, `np.transpose` collects multiple arrays into a new one which is even worse because each step requires to save them in some place of this new array which is even more expensive.

This is a red flag that you're trying to work with data structures numpy is not designed for. Actually, it is slow if you're working with a plenty of small arrays.

However, there are two methods [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) and [`np.ndarray.tobytes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) that are optimized a little bit better for repeated usage. So you could use this advantage and try to mimic behaviour of `np.transpose(dummy_idx)` in a 30% faster way:

```
ls = []
for n in dummy_idx: 
    ls.extend(n.tolist())
x, y = np.fromiter(ls, dtype=dummy_idx[0].dtype).reshape(-1, 2).T
```

and

```
b = bytearray()
for n in dummy_idx: 
    b.extend(n.tobytes())
x, y = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=dummy_idx[0].dtype).reshape(-1, 2).T
```

**Results**

- `zip` - 161 ms
- `np.transpose` - 205 ms
- `np.fromiter` - 117 ms
- `np.frombuffer` - 117 ms
- single looping `dummy_idx` (in comparison) - 16 ms